# TypeScript: Extend React component props for styled component element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

i'm trying to extend a react components props in TypeScript so that it contains all the normal `html` button `attributes`, as well as react specific stuff like `ref`

My understanding is that the type `React.HTMLProps` is what i need, (`React.HTMLAttributes` doesn't contain `ref`)

However, when trying to pass my props to a `styled` component the compiler complains.

My attempt  Codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-cohen-27cpw

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the error message ?

Comment: Yes of course, here's a codesandbox for easier debugging: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-cohen-27cpw

Comment: It's probably got to do with this issue:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/30451

Comment: Adding ```ref?: any``` and ```as?: any``` would resolve the type errors

Answer (score 25):

Couple of things.

Change the typing to:

```
interface Props extends React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'button'> {
  loading?: boolean
  secondary?: boolean
  fullWidth?: boolean
}
```

That should fix the issue for you. I forked your sandbox and it gets rid of the error.

There is also a SO post that this come from that you can use: [Using a forwardRef component with children in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54654303/using-a-forwardref-component-with-children-in-typescript) - the answer details one way but also mentions the answer 1.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to all who helped me get to the bottom of this. What i actually needed was to be able to forward refs to my underlying styled component, i achieved this in TypeScript like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong attributes and SButton cannot access ref.

```
import React, { ButtonHTMLAttributes, DetailedHTMLProps } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

interface Props extends DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement> {
  loading?: boolean;
  secondary?: boolean;
  fullWidth?: boolean;
}

export const Button: React.FC<Props> = p => {
  const { ref, ...buttonProps } = p;
  return <SButton {...buttonProps}>{p.children}</SButton>;
};

export const SButton = styled.button<Props>(
  p => css`
    /*  */
  `
);

render(<Button>Hello world</Button>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

This uses the correct ButtonHTMLAttributes for your props. SButton does not accept ref, that is why its extracted from the button props with `const { ref, ...buttonProps } = p;`. This will leave buttonProps will everything from p except ref.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thing is i want to pass potential refs to the button element. i wonder how correct something like this might be

```
interface Props extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
 loading?: boolean
 secondary?: boolean
 fullWidth?: boolean
 children: React.ReactNode
 className?: string
 ref?: React.Ref<HTMLButtonElement>
}
```

Comment: take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-in-higher-order-components for forwaring refs

Comment: Yes! i just discovered that! - thanks for your help!