# How to make a Modal Component manage its own state in Next.js/React when I can't reference it?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to code a drop-in solution for showing error messages. I want the modal to manage its own state (what text to display, whether the modal is showing at all) instead of the page in which the modal appears.

However, trying to reference the Modal component results in an error saying that I can't do that.

Here's an abridged version of the code that I was trying to get working.

```
import { useRef } from 'react'
import Layout from 'src/client/components/layout'
import Modal from 'src/client/components/modal'

export default function Page() {

    const modalRef = useRef<typeof Modal>()
    const showAlert = (body: string) => {modalRef.current?.showModal(body, 'Error', 'danger');}
/*                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 * ends up being undefined */

    const submitForm = async () => {
        try {
            doThing()
        except (e) {
            showAlert(e.message)
        }
    }

    return (
        <Layout>
            <Content />{/* <-- the specifics don't really matter here */}
            <Modal ref={modalRef} />
{/*                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 * IntelliSense says:
 * Type '{ ref: MutableRefObject<(() => Element) | undefined>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
 * Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)" */}
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

My current implementation of the modal requires the parent to manage the modal's state using 4 `useState()` calls and to change those inside the parent by writing a function for that. This is not scalable and goes against the very point of having a Component in the first place.

```
// counter-example
import { useState } from 'react'
...
export default function Page(){
    // Yuck! Unmaintainable code!
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false)
    const [modalBodyText, setModalBodyText] = useState('')
    const [modalTitleText, setModalTitleText] = useState('')
    const [modalType, setModalType] = useState('')
...
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Content />
            {/* Yuck! Unmaintainable code! */}
            <Modal
                body={bodyText}
                visible={modalVisible}
                title={modalTitle}
                type={modalType} />
        </Layout>
    );
```

I come from a background of HTML and Godot Engine where this kind of stuff is second nature. How can this pattern be implemented in React if a Component can't have a reference from which to call its intrinsic functions?

Here's the implementation of the `Modal` that I want to use:

```
import { forwardRef, useState } from 'react'

export default function Modal() {
    const [bodyText, setBodyText] = useState<string>('')
    const [titleText, setTitleText] = useState<string>('')
    const [type, setType] = useState<string>('')
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState<boolean>(false)

    function showModal(body, type, title) {
        setBodyText(body)
        setTitleText(title)
        setType(type)
        setVisible(true)
    }

    function onClose() {setVisible(false)}

    // styles omitted:
    return visible ? (
        <div className="m_bg">
            <div className="m_box">
                <button
                    type='button'
                    onClick={onClose}
                    >×</button>
                <div className="m_body">
                    <img src={
                        type == 'danger'
                            ? '/images/icon_error.svg'
                            : '/images/icon_info.svg'}
                    ></img>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            {titleText}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            {bodyText}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ) : (
        <div></div>
    )
}
```

Comment: In React, you can achieve this pattern of having a self-managed modal component that can be controlled by its parent component without using useRef. Instead, you can use props and state to manage the modal's behavior.

Comment: How is the `Modal` implemented?

Comment: @prabunaresh - I want to AVOID managing the child's state inside the parent, since the child doesn't need to talk back to the parent about state changes at all. As I said in the quesiton: "My current implementation of the modal requires the parent to manage the modal's state using 4 useState() calls and to change those inside the parent by writing a function for that. This is not scalable and goes against the very point of having a Component in the first place."

Comment: @kinduser - `Modal` is basically an HTML element that is visible if `visible` is true, and invisible if it isn't. It has a close button that sets `visible` to false. It also has `body` for text (and though I didn't include it in the question code, `head` for headline and `type` to choose the icon).

Comment: your problem is with typescript you are typing something wrong; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54654303/using-a-forwardref-component-with-children-in-typescript

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I've never seen `forwardRef` and it seems like it's doing something completely different from what I need to do. How do I use `forwardRef` to define a component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work correctly you need to wrap the `Modal` component with `forwardRef` function and move the `showAlert` function to `useImperativeHandle` function so it is accessible from the parent component.

```
import React from 'react';

const Modal = React.forwardRef((_, ref) => {
  const showModal = (value: string) => {};

  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    showModal: (value: string) => {
      showModal(value);
    }
  }));

  return null;
});

export type ModalHandleProps = {
  showModal: (body: string) => void;
};

const App = () => {
  const modalRef = React.useRef<ModalHandleProps>();
  const showAlert = (body: string) => {modalRef.current?.showModal(body);}

  return (
    <Modal ref={modalRef} />
  );
}
```

**[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4BZCAExQBs4BeRYmAOkzQA7iigtkmABRSA%20gBo4RTAEpuAPjgBvcnDjV68OgAsIw5m048pANw4BXJAC44DKMBoBzNV01aAvhS6vOgC9nRIAJLgSFAoMMA2SAASKDQs7EhSyopSPppSOnp6JmYWHC62Ds6uMO5e%20drBxa6m5qwcVeyOKhQt-sH%20Kr2UekQw9lA0cDT27OwUQ5RIAB6QsHAwAJ5gSHDl7KnpmQAKOGB03E0lbQeVAEasWy5uHt4acDYQwCyLQQYMOAAQTAYCueQ%20RX0tEBIA67EkV2QoX44SQkgAPAcjhkkGcIBd1Hk%20sUAUY2kDMhtrI8WM9avV3r5tHDLJJ%20GhJkQaDAAPz8UrtSxSWlbXoDZpKJATKZwKSSvRY%20FSzBcLSsjiSfxwAD06klIwGQA)**

Comment: That's not compatible with having a `Modal` Component in a different file, is it? I need to use this Component from multiple pages. [Edit:] Nevermind, I just split it by `const App = () => {` and it worked

Comment: @haley Everywhere you want to use `Modal` and call it's `showModal` function from the parent, you need to use `useRef` for it, thats all.