# Using a forwardRef on a generic target using arrow functions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

Similar to [Using a forwardRef component with children in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54654303/using-a-forwardref-component-with-children-in-typescript) but I am looking for an example where the referenced object is also generic like react-native FlashList or FlatList

I got it to work like this

```js
export const DragFlashList = forwardRef<FlashList<any>, DragFlashListProps<any>>((props, ref) => <DragListImpl {...props} ref={ref} />);
```

but I want to get rid of the `any`

or this doesn't work

```
export function DragFlashList<T>  {
    return forwardRef<FlashList<T>, DragFlashListProps<T>>((props, ref) => <DragListImpl {...props} ref={ref} />);
}
```

But I want it to use arrow functions.

The technique I did [What is the syntax for Typescript arrow functions with generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308370/what-is-the-syntax-for-typescript-arrow-functions-with-generics/74204319#74204319) doesn't appear to do work correctly because `forwardRef` builds the function.  The following isn't valid typescript

```js
export const DragFlashList = <T,>forwardRef<FlashList<T>, DragFlashListProps<T>>((props, ref) => <DragListImpl {...props} ref={ref} />);
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
export const forwardRefGeneric = <P, R>(fc: (props: P, ref: ForwardedRef<R>) => JSX.Element) => {
    return forwardRef(fc) as unknown as (props: P & { ref: ForwardedRef<R> }) => JSX.Element;
}
```

usage:

```
export function DragFlashList<T>() {
    return forwardRefGeneric<FlashList<T>, DragFlashListProps<T>>((props, ref) => <DragListImpl {...props} ref={ref} />);
}
```